# unexpected behaviour when trying to do math in for loop

Tags: python, hex, exponent

while trying to make simple code to convert hex to decimal:

```
#Hex multiply by 16 depending on position: 0xAB = A*16 + B = 10*16 
    #0x375
    #3*(16**2) + 7*(16**1) + 5
```

i needed to reverse the number because the exponent of `16` would increase to the right

```
def tohex(integer): #375
    power = 0
    l = [num for num in str(integer)] #['3','7','5']
    l.reverse()                       #['5','7','3']
    for i, n in enumerate(l):         # OK
        number = int(n)               # OK
        l[i] = n*(16**power)          # ???
        print(l[i])
        power + 1

    l.reverse()

    return "".join(l)


print(tohex(375))
```

output:

```
─$ python3 hextobase64.py
5
7
3
375
```

it looks to me `l[i] = n*(16**power)` isn't doing anything at all. why is this?

edit:
fixed version:

```
def tohex(integer): #375
    power = 0
    f = []
    l = [num for num in str(integer)] #['3','7','5']
    l.reverse()                       #['5','7','3']
    for n in l:       # OK
        number = int(n)
        f.append(number*(16**power))
        power += 1

    return sum(f)

print(tohex(375))

└─$ python3 hextobase64.py
885
```

last edit:
made function to translate `abcdef` to `10 11 12 13 14 15`:

```
def removeletter(list):
    #function to convert all letters in decimal to hex for todecimal()

    for i, letter in enumerate(list):
        if letter in hextable.keys():
            list[i] = hextable[letter]
        
    return list

hextable = {}
for number, letter in enumerate(lowers[:6]):
    hextable[letter] = number + 10

def todecimal(h):   
    power = 0
    l = [num for num in str(h)] #['3', 'a', '2', 'f']
    l = removeletter(l)
    l.reverse()                       #['f', '2', 'a', '3'] 

    for i, n in enumerate(l):
        
        number = int(n)
        l[i] = number*(16**power)
        power += 1

    l.reverse()
    return sum(l)

print(todecimal('49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d'))
```

output:

```
python3 hextobase64.py
11259432467145572969189485457381052543241507215288737798329079056359121649591228422793827173000297562297701340508013
```

Comment: `power + 1` That line doesn't do anything.  Perhaps you meant `power += 1`?

Comment: `n*(16**power)` is presumably supposed to be `number*(16**power)` , and `power + 1` needs to be `power += 1`. You're currently doing string multiplication, and only multiplying it by 1 because `power` is always `0`.

Comment: hahaha what a simple fix, i couldn't spot that.

Comment: `>>> hex(375)
>>>'0x177'
`What are you even doing?

Comment: @VisheshMangla Looking at the code, I think OP is trying to convert Hex to decimal

Comment: thanks @ShivamRoy , that should be it

Comment: @shivamroy yep thats what i meant

Answer (score 1):

`power + 1` to `power+=1`... very simple fix

Comment: OP is also using the wrong variable in the line `l[i] = n*(16**power)` , he is multiplying `n` instead of `number`. Also, he is finally returning the digits in the list, whereas the digits in the list need to added to be converted to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question you're converting a `hexadecimal` number to `decimal`.You are using the wrong variable in the line `l[i] = n*(16**power)` , you are multiplying `n` instead of `number`.And as everyone mentioned you should use `power += 1` to increment power in every iteration. Also, you are finally returning the digits in the list, whereas the digits in the list need to added to be converted to decimal.
Made a few changes to the code:

```
def tohex(integer): 
    power = 0
    l = [num for num in str(integer)] 
    l.reverse()                       
    for i, n in enumerate(l):         
        number = int(n)               
        l[i] = number*(16**power)          
        power += 1

    l.reverse()    
    return sum(l)

print(tohex(375))
```

Output:

```
885
```